# JSS sitecore multiple projects under same solution

Tags: jss, helix

Hi i am following `Helix` principle in `JSS` sitecore first approach. I am new to `react`. I need to have a multiple projects under same solution setup.

Here my [solution sample](https://github.com/andiappan-ar/sitecore.first-jss-helix.git).

SafariZoo is my project and i am maintaining all my sample Zoo project related files under the `Src/Project` folder. Like below picture. By this way i can reuse the feature components between multiple projects as per `Helix` principle.

[image]

Here in react `index.js` will have a initial call, how we can configure different projects for `approot.js` and how we can run and develop our app.

Answer (score 3):

I would not advise to align the front-end project to Helix. It was build with back-end in mind and trying to fit that into the front-end way of doing things will cause unnecessary complication and friction. I'd recommend looking into monorepos and tooling like Lerna if you want to split the codebase (have component library and a separate "app" project for example) and maintain a smooth developer experience.
Lerna:
https://github.com/lerna/lerna and a good read on monorepos:
https://codeburst.io/monorepos-by-example-part-1-3a883b49047e

Comment: Hi @Alex Shyba, I used mono repo concept and lerna here. Babel causing issue here i mentioned..https://stackoverflow.com/q/54969942/2632619. Cant able to share the components in mono repo.